# Express /register not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm using MEAN Stack for my system. I'm having a problem on my backend where I cannot register my user.

authService.js

```js
app.factory('auth', [
    '$http',
    '$window',
    function($http, $window) {
        var auth = {};

        auth.saveToken = function(token) {
            $window.localStorage['caretel-token'] = token;
        };

        auth.getToken = function() {
            return $window.localStorage['caretel-token'];
        }

        auth.isLoggedIn = function() {
            var token = auth.getToken();

            if (token) {
                var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

                return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };

        auth.currentUser = function() {
            if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                var token = auth.getToken();
                var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

                return payload.username;
            }
        };

        auth.register = function(user) {
            console.log("--> Proceed to backend");
            return $http.post('/register', user).success(function(data) {
                auth.saveToken(data.token);
            });
        };

        auth.logIn = function(user) {
            return $http.post('/login', user).success(function(data) {
                auth.saveToken(data.token);
            });
        };

        auth.logOut = function() {
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('caretel-token');
        };

        return auth;
    }
]);
```

The data went through here but then I'm not sure what happen.

These are the related backend file:

passport.js

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

And this is the schema:

Users.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
 hash: String,
 salt: String
});

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
 this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

 this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
 var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');

 return this.hash === hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function(){

 //set expiration to 60 days
 var today = new Date();
 var exp = new Date(today);
 exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

 return jwt.sign({
  _id: this._id,
  username: this.username,
  exp: parseInt(exp.getTime()/1000),
 }, 'SECRET');
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In case if you want to see my app.js:

app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Books');
require('./models/Users');
require('./config/passport');
//Connect to local db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/office');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the image of my error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs1do.png)

How do I know if my jsonwebtoken is functioning? How do I solve this?

Comment: Where is your `/register'` route defined in express?

Comment: I can't find a route and function defined for registration. Please add it

Comment: Owh, sorry I didn't notice that. I was too tired. Thank you